# jQuery ajax POST consuming returned JSON object

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to consume a JSON response sent from the server. Firebug shows that the JSON object returned from the server is valid, but for some reason, the code below fails ... :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function isValidEmailAddress(email){
// do something ...
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").on("submit", function(e){
        if ( isValidEmailAddress($('#invite-email').val()) ) {
            // setup some local variables
            var $form = $(this),
                // let's select and cache all the fields
                $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea"),
                // serialize the data in the form
                serializedData = $form.serialize();

            // let's disable the inputs for the duration of the ajax request
            $inputs.attr("disabled", "disabled");

            // fire off the request to /form.php
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo $url; ?>',
                type: "post",
                data: serializedData,
                // callback handler that will be called on success
                success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
                    var is_ok = response.error_code == 0 ? true : false;  // array access also fails 
                    var msg = response.msg; // array access also fails 

                    alert(is_ok);
                    alert(msg);

                    if (is_ok){
                        $('#invite-member').text(msg);
                    }
                    else{
                        $('#error-msg').text(msg);
                        $('#error-msg').show("slow");                        
                    }
                },
                // callback handler that will be called on error
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    // log the error to the console
                    console.log(
                        "The following error occured: "+
                        textStatus, errorThrown
                    );
                },
                // callback handler that will be called on completion
                // which means, either on success or error
                complete: function(){
                    // enable the inputs
                    $inputs.removeAttr("disabled");
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            $('#invite-email').val('');
        }

        return false;
    });
});

</script>
```

I am obviously doing something stupid - but I can't seem to be able to put my finger on it. What am I missing?

Comment: We need more information... What is the expected structure of the returned JSON? How is it "not working"?

Comment: Example returned JSON object is: `{"data":{"error_code":-1,"msg":"Sorry, this email is already registered. Please try again"}}`. The 'error' is that I cannot retrieve the error_code and msg fields from the JSON object sent from the server (even though it is didplsyed correctly in the Firebug console window).

Comment: @PeterAdrian: I added `dataType: 'json'` to the ajax call code, but the problem (inability to access the returned JSON object fields) remains.

Comment: @riskio: `alert(is_ok);` and `alert(msg);` return `false` and `undefined` respectively. The 'error' is the (apparent) inability to access the fields of the returned JSON object. I suspect though that I have to extract the data object first.  I'll try that.

Comment: Yes, it turned out that I had got the nesting level of the returned JSON object wrong. I had to retrieve the nested data object first.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting this varibales at startup.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    contentType : 'application/json',
    dataType : "json"
});
```

They tell jQUery that the return datatype has to be interpreted as JSON.